# Checkbox is not checked when click on modal Agree button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox with link tag. My modal is open when click on link tag. I have modal when click on button then checkbox is checked

```
<div class="form-check form-check-radios">
   <label class="form-check-label">
         <input class="form-check-input number" type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="termsChk">I agree with
        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
        </label> <a href="#termsModal" data-toggle="modal">"Terms and Condition"</a>
</div>
```

I want when i click on agree button then checkbox is checked. Issue in my modal checkbox is not checked when click on agree button

Here is my modal code

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="termsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
      labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms and Conditions</h4>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody1" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:70%;  margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <p style="text-align:justify;" id="modalTerms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non ipsum at magna finibus rhoncus a vitae leo. Phasellus id nibh luctus, gravida elit pellentesque, consectetur sem. Nulla fringilla, nulla et egestas rhoncus, sem risus iaculis neque, eget aliquam mauris erat vitae nulla. Vivamus placerat est lectus, ac molestie orci tincidunt a. Aliquam ac viverra sapien, sed vestibulum ex. Fusce malesuada ut arcu at porttitor. Cras suscipit leo vel varius venenatis. Nullam aliquam non elit a lacinia.

     Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.

     Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.

   Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.
  </p>
          </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" disabled aria-hidden="true" id="agreeBtn">Agree</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is jquery code

```
$('#agreeBtn').click(function(){
  alert("btn click");
  $("#termsChk").attr('checked');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should pass a value to the attr, `.attr('checked', 'checked')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jquery code, attr() takes 2 args - the property and its value:

```
 $('#agreeBtn').click(function(){
  alert("btn click");
  $('#termsChk').attr('checked', true);
});
```

For more ways of setting checkbox value using jquery, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try $('#termsChk').prop('checked', true);

Comment: you should format your code and explain what it does :)